# Correct Syntax for uploading files to custom directory in Wordpress

Tags: php, uploads, attachments, forms, directory

I have current PHP code that works when attaching files on a form. The files have to go to a certain directory. I know that while attaching in Wordpress I need to use a different syntax. However, I've been reading for days literally on how I can do this. Again, my code here works on a standalone PHP page but not in Wordpress. I'm not that worried about security either since my page is on an intranet site behind a firewall and cannot be reached otherwise. I see some tutorials and code for uploading to a custom directory in the WP uploads folder, but I need to upload to a directory in the root of the web server. Here's my code currently from the standalone PHP page.

```
$folderPath = "/jobtracking/files/standard/{$projID}";
mkdir($folderPath);

$filename = basename($_FILES["Attach_Files"]["name"]);
$filetype = $_FILES["Attach_Files"]["type"];
$datei = "/jobtracking/files/standard/{$projID}/{$filename}";
$target_path = $folderPath . "/" . $filename;
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["Attach_Files"]["tmp_name"], $target_path)) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO files(files.name, files.project, files.added, files.datei, files.type, files.folder) VALUES('{$filename}', '{$projID}', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()), '{$datei}', '{$filetype}', 0)");
    }
chmod("{$target_path}", 0777);
```

I've seen the codex on wp_handle_upload but not sure if that applies to my need. I feel like that's what I need to use but having a hard time finding anything that fits what I'm trying to do. I don't need the form attachment to go into Wordpress at all.

I saw this [article](http://yoast.com/smarter-upload-handling-wp-plugins/) which seemed promising but it is still uploading to putting files inside the WP directory and not outside.

Also tried to use [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201672/php-image-upload-wordpress-custom-plug-in) as reference.

My question is how can I have a single file attachment form field in a custom Wordpress Page Template to follow my current PHP and upload to a custom directory outside of WP?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

**Update 12.13.13

I tried using site_url to establish the correct folder path but still no luck. Here's the code I tried so far.

```
$folderPath = site_url('/jobtracking/files/standard/{$projID}');
mkdir($folderPath);
$filename = basename($_FILES["Attach_Files"]["name"]);
$filetype = $_FILES["Attach_Files"]["type"];
$datei = site_url('/jobtracking/files/standard/{$projID}/{$filename}');
$target_path = $folderPath . "/" . $filename;
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["Attach_Files"]["tmp_name"], $target_path)) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO files(files.name, files.project, files.added, files.datei, files.type, files.folder) VALUES('{$filename}', '{$projID}', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()), '{$datei}', '{$filetype}', 0)");
    }
chmod("{$target_path}", 0777);
```

**Update: 01.31.14

It seems that I'm not even getting a directory created on form submission. The folders are all set to 0777 for now just to make sure I have all the read/write privileges I need for my test. I also read about using wp_mkdir_p(); instead of mkdir(); when using Wordpress. I don't know if I can use a variable for the string in the wp_mkdir_p();. As soon as I can get the directory to create and the file to move in, I feel like I'm halfway there.

**Update: 02.03.14

```
$folderPath = ABSPATH . '/jobtracking/files/standard/{$projID}';

wp_mkdir_p($folderPath, 0777, true);

$filename = basename($_FILES['Attach_Files']['name']);
$filetype = $_FILES['Attach_Files']['type'];
$datei = ABSPATH . 'files/standard/{$projID}/{$filename}';
$target_path = $folderPath . "/" . $filename;
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Attach_Files']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO files (files.name, files.project, files.user, files.added, files.datei, files.type, files.folder) VALUES('{$filename}', '{$projID}', 0, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()), '{$datei}', '{$filetype}', 0)");
    }
chmod("{$target_path}", 0777);
```

**Update 02.04.14 - - This creates the directory and puts the file in it. However, information still not entering the database. Maybe I'm not using the if(); correctly?

```
$folderPath = "/jobtracking/files/standard/{$projID}";

mkdir(ABSPATH.$folderPath, 0777, true);

$filename = basename($_FILES['Attach_Files']['name']);
$filetype = $_FILES['Attach_Files']['type'];
$datei = 'files/standard/{$projID}/{$filename}';
$target_path = ABSPATH.$folderPath . "/" . $filename;
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Attach_Files']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO files (files.name, files.project, files.user, files.added, files.datei, files.type, files.folder) VALUES('{$filename}', '{$projID}', 0, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()), '{$datei}', '{$filetype}', 0)");
    }
chmod("{$target_path}", 0777);
```

**Update 02.04.14 - IT WORKS!!! Here's my code:

```
$folderPath = "/jobtracking/files/standard/{$projID}";

mkdir(ABSPATH.$folderPath, 0777, true);

$filename = basename($_FILES['Attach_Files']['name']);
$filetype = $_FILES['Attach_Files']['type'];
$datei = "files/standard/{$projID}/{$filename}";
$target_path = ABSPATH.$folderPath . "/" . $filename;
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Attach_Files']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO files (files.name, files.project, files.user, files.added, files.datei, files.type, files.folder, files.visible) VALUES('{$filename}', '{$projID}', 5, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()), '{$datei}', '{$filetype}', 0, ' ')");
    }
chmod("{$target_path}", 0777);
```

Comment: The directory will never be created. Because you're are using `site_url` its a URI address, you need directory base path. Try using `ABSPATH` this is wordpress root path constant. And yes try `wp_mkdir_p` to create directories. have you tried it?

Comment: Firstly, thanks @RahilWazir for responding. Any help I can get at this point is monumental. I tried to include your notes in my revision. See my latest code update above which does not work.

Comment: Which part is not working for you? Have you debugged every single line of your code?

Comment: It's not creating the directory. That's what I consider my next step. I feel that if I can at least get the PHP to create the directory, I'll be moving in the right direction. Still double-checking the code against everything I can. Using Dreamweaver to write the code and it doesn't spot any syntax errors. I'm still reading about URI and ABSPATH.

Comment: `mkdir(ABSPATH.$folderPath, 0777, true);`

This created the directory, but now the file does not show up in the directory. One step at a time.

Comment: Thanks @RahilWazir your advice did help! See my revised working code at the bottom above. Cheers!

Comment: Mathew thats great that you sorted out. Please explain how did you solve the issue by posting an answer below, so others should know this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Update to answer: 05.27.15) What finally worked is using ABSPATH:

```
$folderPath = "/jobtracking/files/standard/{$projID}";

mkdir(ABSPATH.$folderPath, 0755, true);

$filename = basename($_FILES['Attach_Files']['name']);
$filetype = $_FILES['Attach_Files']['type'];
$datei = "files/standard/{$projID}/{$filename}";
$target_path = ABSPATH.$folderPath . "/" . $filename;
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Attach_Files']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO files (files.name, files.project, files.user, files.added, files.datei, files.type, files.folder, files.visible) VALUES('{$filename}', '{$projID}', 5, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()), '{$datei}', '{$filetype}', 0, ' ')");
}
chmod("{$target_path}", 0755);
```

I also made sure to change the 0777 to 0755.

Comment: Could you add some details around your code on how to use it and why it answers the question?

Comment: I cringe when I see `0777`. If there is a `PUT` handler on the server, _everybody_ can write anything to that directory. This is really bad.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the updates to this question from over a year ago. What worked for me is using the:
mkdir(ABSPATH.$folderPath, 0755, true);